# Connect Sharepoint Online WebServiceProxy

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need some help with sharepoint online, so far I've been using WebServiceProxy to pull information from on premise sharepoint. However, it no longer works with sharepoint online.
Can anyone help me with the powershell script, i will add that there is ADFS on the way if that changes anything.

```
*$RestOut = Invoke-RestMethod @Request
$credPAM = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($RestOut.UserName, $($RestOut.Content | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force))
Function getPSListItems ([String]$ListName, $WebServiceProxy)
{
$xmlDoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument            
$viewFields = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields")            
$queryOptions = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions")            
$query = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query")
$rowLimit = "10000"    
$list = $service.GetListItems($listName, "", $query, $viewFields, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, "")
return $list
}
$uri = "http://my-url/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?WSDL"
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace SpWs -Credential $credPAM
$listName = 'Apps'
$d = getPSListItems -ListName $listName -WebServiceProxy $service*
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, It is important to install on your computer SharePoint Online Components and indicate the correct path to the files:

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$UserName = "username@user.com"
$Pass = "password123456"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $Pass -AsPlainText -Force
$SiteUrl = "https://sharepoint.com/sites/SHP"
$ListName = "ListName"
$Filename = $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
$ExportFile = "C:\user"

$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$Password)
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials
  
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$context.Load($ListItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$ListItemCollection = @() 

 $ListItems |  foreach {
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Name" -value $_["Title"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Version" -value $_["field_1"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Date" -value $_["field_2"]

    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
 }

$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV $ExportFile -Encoding Default -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation
```